# SQL Calculating a percentage of a column using count function

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a allergy column in my database, if someone doesn't have an allergy the value is 'N/A' and if someone does have an allergy, the name of the allergy is present.

I am trying to use SQL and the COUNT function to calculate the percentage of people where allergy != 'N/A'.

Although I am stuck can anyone point me in the right direction please or anyone where there is a useful resource.

```
Customer | Allergy
--------------------
   A     | Nut allergy
   B     | N/A
   C     | N/A
```

Comment: Any sample data,Or code?? Show us the code where you are stuck. You cannot expect us to solve your issue. Try yourself. If you get stuck ask us.

Comment: Please add your original best effort where you got stuck, that would show research effort and might help the "answer" guys to better adapt to why you got stuck in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
select sum(case when allergy <> 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*)
from your_table
```

Comment: That would count allergy IS NULL as allergic, right?

Comment: Yes, it would.. but since there is 'N/A' for no allergy - I highly doubt NULL values exists

Comment: Yes, probable assumption.

Comment: @Dilettant - no it would not as `NULL <> NOT NULL` is always false - try it with `SELECT CASE WHEN NULL <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL` the output will be `0`.

Comment: @MT0: But the condition of my query: `allergy <> 'N/A'` will be FALSE when compared to NULL. So it counts as allergic. Because the condition is NOT ALLERGIC

Comment: No, when allergy is either `'N/A'` or `NULL` your case statement will give an output of `0` and for any other value will give an output of `1` so you are counting the percentage of people who are allergic - but this is what the OP is after as they want to count the people where `allergy != 'N/A'` (so not having no allergies - note the double negative).

Comment: Adding `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('D', NULL);` will result in 25 as result, thus counting `NULL` as allergic and adequately counting the norm as `4` via the `count(*)` which I think is good with rational math ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant surely if NULL was counted as being allergic, you'd get a result of 50%? 25% indicates 1 out of the 4 rows is an allergy, showing that NULL is counted as not being allergic - entirely as expected with this query.

Comment: @Boneist thanks, you are right, I was wrong. So: Norm counts `NULL` in (ok) but CASE statement condition as is, does map `NULL` to `N/A` class.

Comment: @Dilettant `COUNT(*)` (or `COUNT(1)`) counts the number of rows so is independent of whether any column value within that row is `NULL` or non-`NULL` and, for your example would give a count of 4; whereas `COUNT( allergy )` will count only the non-`NULL` values and, for your example, would give a count of 3.

Comment: @MT0 yes, this is what I meant with "Norm counts `NULL`in (ok)" but as I am not a native English writer it might be badly expressed. I was far too focused on the denominator (`count(*)` vs. `count(column_name)` behavior w.r.t. `NULL` which distracted me from the above well stated facts on `NULL` comparison behavior in the first place I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

This will give the percentage of people who have a non-`N/A` value for the `allergy` column (and will ignore people who have an unknown [`NULL`] value for allergy):

```
SELECT 100 * COUNT( DECODE( allergy, 'N/A', NULL, allergy ) )
           / COUNT( allergy )
           AS percentage_with_allergy
FROM   table_name
```

To include `NULL` values as if they were `N/A` then:

```
SELECT 100 * COUNT( DECODE( allergy, 'N/A', NULL, allergy ) )
           / COUNT( 1 )
           AS percentage_with_allergy
FROM   table_name
```

Comment: Upvoted both your and @juergen d answers as offer good beginner usable material. The "other" answer might profit from updating based on the comments - but we are still awaiting the certified original best effort query variant from the OP ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to use `avg()` with conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when allergy <> 'N/A' then 100.0 else 0 end)
from t;
```

If `allergy` could be `NULL`, the above will treat it as 'N/A'.  If you really only wanted to count non-N/A values:

```
select avg(case when allergy = 'N/A' then 0.0 else 100.0 end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Since my friends have already queried in couple of answers it is not **right/ethical to copy and paste their answers**. Hence going with a more convntional or simpler query. Please find the query below.

```
select (A_SUM/(select count(1) from al_table))*100 as percent from (
select count(1) A_sum from al_table where (allergy <>'N/A' or allergy is not null));
```

Comment: I did not vote on your answer, but am curious, if Oracle allows the sub query without an alias in the from clause? PostgreSQL tells me: `ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias` - does the query work on your database at hand in that way?

Comment: i have tried it and it is displaying me the correct output. I can provide you with the screenshot as well.

Comment: Not my downvote but this is more complicated than just using `COUNT` with a `CASE` or `DECODE` statement and, if you check the explain plan, you will see that you may end up doing two full-table scans which will make the query more inefficient.

Comment: Thanks - I was just curious, open to learn, not dubiously ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant I am the same way to. I was just curious to find a work around and hence i tried this query and i wanted to share it. But got a down vote. Great!!

Comment: @MT0 Iknow this is not efficient way but like i told others have already showed the query based on case which i know is the most proficient way. Just for a learning cause i have just shown a work around, Anyway cheers.

Comment: Many people, many opinions and expectations, often scarcity in gentleness and friendliness - hard to make better, easy to worsen. Next time more luck :-)